# Truncate Table throwing error

Tags: mysql, sql

im trying  to truncate table and set auto increment. I looked already in asket questions and I wrote exactly as in responses and this is not helping me. i keep getting an error.
i realy cant understand what is the problem.........

here the error :

```
        Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:      Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREMENT = '1'' at line 2' in /var/www/DBWork-master/DBWork/Truncate.php on line 56
```

here the query output:

```
'TRUNCATE TABLE `people` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to truncate a table is just `TRUNCATE [TABLE] tbl_name`. The `AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` is the syntax error.

As for resetting the `AUTO_INCREMENT`, this is done automatically from MySQL 5.0.13. Before that it also did so except for InnoDB tables with foreign key constraints (and before 5.0.3 it didn't do so for any InnoDB table). If this is relevant then just run `ALTER TABLE people AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` after truncating the table.

See the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html).